# why cant i subtract from a variable inside a switch?

Tags: javascript

before i begin i want to say sorry i don't write very neat i am very new to java (this is my 5th day or so). i am trying to to make a little web browser game from just text (to be used in the console developer tool) it is inspired by undertale and my problem is that when i subtract from an enemies health inside of the switch it doesnt do anything. here is the code to this point:

```
var health = (20)
var weapon = ('copper sword(5 DMG)')
var damage = (5)

//for npc's: name = [health, damage]
var playerstats = (name + ": health = " + health + ", weapon = " + weapon)
var skeleton1stats = [5, 5]

var name = prompt("Hi, what's your name?")
alert("Welcome " + name + " Are you ready to play Monster Fighter?")

alert("HINT: there will be messages in the log that you also should read. when a message like this appears click ok to continue")
alert("HINT: read log messages before dialog boxes, as the log messages are made before the dialog boxes are.")

console.log("Lets begin!")

console.log("You are walking through a forest when you trip and fall into a dark pit...")
console.log("As you are walking around a cave the pit lead you to, you are approached by a skeleton")
console.log("The skeleton tells you that he can lead you to safety")

alert("HINT: when you come across a character such as this one you will have multiple options, 3 of which are usually: fight, flee, and stats")
alert("HINT: I would recommend before fighting any character you view their stats.")

var skeleton1 = prompt("Do you choose to: TRUST, FIGHT, FLEE, STATS").toUpperCase()

switch (skeleton1) {

case 'TRUST':
console.log("The skeleton brings you to a dead end and stabs you doing 5 damage to you, and you hit him back doing 5 damage to him.");
skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
health - 5
break;

case 'FIGHT':
console.log("You thrust your sword through the skeleton doing 5 damage to the skeleton.");
skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
break;

case 'FLEE':
console.log("You make a run for it, but he catches up to you and stabs you dealing 5 damage to you. laying next to you is a iron sword(7 DMG), you picked it up and hit him with it doing 7 damage to him.");
health - 5;
skeleton1stats[0] - 7;
weapon = 'iron sword(7 DMG)'
damage = 7
break;

case 'STATS':
    console.log(playerstats + ", skeleton: health = " + skeleton1stats[0] + ", damage = " + skeleton1stats[1])
    var skeleton1 = prompt("Do you choose to: TRUST, FIGHT, FLEE").toUpperCase()
    switch (skeleton1) {
        case 'TRUST':
            console.log("The skeleton brings you to a dead end and stabs you doing 5 damage to you, and you hit him back doing 5 damage to him.");
            skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
            health - 5
        break;
        case 'FIGHT':
            console.log("You thrust your sword through the skeleton doing 5 damage to the skeleton.");
            skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
        break;
        case 'FLEE':
            console.log("You make a run for it, but he catches up to you and stabs you dealing 5 damage to you. laying next to you is a iron sword(7 DMG), you picked it up and hit him with it doing 7 damage to him.");
            health - 5;
            skeleton1stats[0] - 7;                
            weapon = 'iron sword(7 DMG)'
            damage = 7
        break;
        default:
            alert("ALERT: you must restart the game.")       
        break;
}
break;

default:
    alert("ALERT: if you do not enter one of the choices this time you will have to restart the game.")
    var skeleton1 = prompt("Do you choose to: TRUST, FIGHT, FLEE, STATS").toUpperCase()
    switch (skeleton1) {
        case 'TRUST':
            console.log("The skeleton brings you to a dead end and stabs you doing 5 damage to you, and you hit him back doing 5 damage to him.");
            skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
            health - 5
        break;
        case 'FIGHT':
            console.log("You thrust your sword through the skeleton doing 5 damage to the skeleton.");
            skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
        break;
        case 'FLEE':
            console.log("You make a run for it, but he catches up to you and stabs you dealing 5 damage to you. laying next to you is a iron sword(7 DMG), you picked it up and hit him with it doing 7 damage to him.");
            health - 5;
            skeleton1stats[0] - 7;              
            weapon = 'iron sword(7 DMG)'
            damage = 7
        break;
        case 'STATS':
            console.log(playerstats + ", skeleton: health = " + skeleton1stats[0] + ", damage = " + skeleton1stats[1])
        var skeleton1 = prompt("Do you choose to: TRUST, FIGHT, FLEE").toUpperCase()
        switch (skeleton1) {
            case 'TRUST':
                console.log("The skeleton brings you to a dead end and stabs you doing 5 damage to you, and you hit him back doing 5 damage to him.");
                skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
                health - 5
            break;
            case 'FIGHT':
                console.log("You thrust your sword through the skeleton doing 5 damage to the skeleton.");
                skeleton1stats[0] - 5;
            break;
            case 'FLEE':
                console.log("You make a run for it, but he catches up to you and stabs you dealing 5 damage to you. laying next to you is a iron sword(7 DMG), you picked it up and hit him with it doing 7 damage to him.");
                health - 5;
                skeleton1stats[0] - 7;
                weapon = 'iron sword(7 DMG)'
                damage = 7
            break;
            default:
                alert("ALERT: you must restart the game.")       
            break;
}
            break;
            default:
                alert("ALERT: you must restart the game.")       
            break;
}
            break;
}

if(skeleton1stats[0] < 1) {
console.log("You defeated the skeleton!") }

console.log("You continue down the cave further...")
console.log("far into the cave you see light, but coming from it are 3 zombies!")
console.log("Fairies then appear and kill the zombies and tell you to follow them to the 'hallow'")
console.log("in the hallow there are many fairies and the biggest one of them, the queen says she needs your help slaying these monsters that have begun appearing near the hallow")

var helpsfairies = confirm("will you help the fairies?")

if(helpsfairies) {
console.log("The fairies thank you and show you the way to a cave that they have seen many zombies in lately")
} else {
    console.log("The queen puts you under a spell and you help them anyway...") }
```

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.io)

Comment: `health - 5` you are not assigning the resulting value to anything

Comment: *"inside of the switch it doesnt do anything"* - Note that the same code *outside* of a switch wouldn't do anything either. The switch statement is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the value back to the variable:

I.e.

```
health = health - 5;
```

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: Or simply, `health -= 5`

Comment: thank you ill go change that! it is very nice how fast you guys answered i just want you to know im thankful for such an awesome community!